# Unable to produce ripples on RecyclerView's item (CardView)

Tags: android, android-cardview

I am using a `RecyclerView` with its item as a `CardView`. I have the card view's background as `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`.

I tried setting the `foreground`, tried giving a `LinearLayout` as a parent and set its background etc, but nothing works.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <!--TextView-->
        <!--Imageview-->
        <!--Textview-->
   </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Why is this behavior?

Edit: The `CardView` has an `onClickListener` which works.

Edit 2: I added a `RelativeLayout` as a parent to the `CardView`. And made that clickable and gave it a selectable item background. Still no ripples.

```
 <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:focusable="true">

      <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
          xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
          card_view:cardElevation="2dp">

          <!-- ... -->

      </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit 3: I posting my exact layout code structure. I had failed to mention the data binding part. But I hope that is not blocking the ripples.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
         <import type="android.view.View"/>
         <variable
             name="viewModel"
             type="com.xxx.xxx.viewmodel.genericviewmodel" />
    </data>


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/c_open_case_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <!--TextView-->
            <!--Imageview-->
            <!--Textview-->
            <!--TextView-->
            <!--Imageview-->
            <!--Textview-->
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

Comment: Where you get this layout from? i mean from `layout` resources folder

Comment: Set it clickable and focusable.

Comment: @MD : yes, I get it from the layout resources folder.

Comment: @GergelyKőrössy : I have tried the clickable and focussable stuff. Nothing works..

Comment: What Android version are you using?

Comment: @Ashwin Are you done?

Comment: @MD : Nope. Still doesnt work for me

Comment: @Ashwin You should load layout from `layout-v21` and also load drawable from `drawable-v21`

Comment: @MD : I don't think that should be the solution. I have been able to produce ripples before working from layout itself. This is a one-off case where anything I do doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

*Update:* After all trials to reproduce your problem, I think that there is no problem with `CardView`s or data binding. If you're not satisfied with the answer, you can always [submit a bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry) to the Android dev team.

---

Use `android:foreground` and make sure that the `CardView` is clickable:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp">

    <!-- ... -->

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: @Vujasin manojilovic : doesn't work

Comment: @Ashwin Which version of Android are you using? I use this method in my app and it works. Did you try implementation of a custom `RippleDrawable`?

Comment: Manojlovic : Marshmallow

Comment: @Ashwin I'm on Marshmallow too and can't reproduce your problem. I'm using the layout which is in the question (`CardView` > `RelativeLayout` > `TextView`s and `ImageView`). See [this screenshot](http://imgur.com/O98DX0p). The problem is somewhere else. Ping me if you want to send you the sample code.

Comment: Manojlovic : yes, I would like to see your code.

Comment: @Ashwin I've used [Android RecyclerView Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RecyclerView) with modified [`text_row_item.xml`](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/df043e0235cc9ac9bd6f).

Comment: Manoklovic : Hey, my layout is similar to that of yours. I have added some extra info in EDIT 3. Check it out.

Comment: @Ashwin I've implemented data binding and ripples were shown on `CardView` click. Without the original code, I can't reproduce the problem.